# Bitbucket code changes are not shown properly?

Tags: java, eclipse, git, bitbucket, bitbucket-server

I am facing issue with code format in bitbucket. After done with few lines of  code changes in eclipse and committing my changes using git repo viewer. But, my code changes are not displayed properly in bitbucket repo page. Please see the attached screenshot.[image]

Answer (score 0):

I see there a 4000+ lines of code modified in your ThirdPartyCashReconciliation.java

It can cause such problems.

Note that if you format your code (changing the tab indentation by blank indentation for exemple), it count like a line change.

Is it the first time you encounter such problems or is it systematic ? Event in the case of a single line change ?

Comment: Hi Oreste Viron, In ThirdPartyCashReconciliation.java file I was changed 90 lines of code but it was displayed like 4860 lines added and 4770 removed and code is not formated in eclipse. and second one like I just changed one single line code change in first file but its shows "lot of code changes" not displayed updated change. This is not the first time I was faced this issue.